# How do I open a new terminal different from the default terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[According to the official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_common-questions) its quite easy to change the default shell for vscode from say Powershell to Bash. However, what if I want multiple default shells or to launch a new shell of a different type, lets say the php or python interperter in REPL mode? I know I can open a new terminal and run the python repl on top of the default shell, but it seems a little annoying.

Basically, is there some kind of command or something where I can launch a new shell in the integrated terminal, and have that be not the default shell and not be running on top of the default shell so that if I quit the shell, I don't have a shell running under it?

Answer (score 6):

Looking through issues on VSCode's repo this ability does not seem to be on the future plans list for them. Microsoft states in a few to use [this shell launcher extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.shell-launcher), which oddly enough was written by one of the engineers on the VS Code team.

Which testing out on my machine works well. Just adding the `shell.launcher.windows` to my settings threw this code block into the settings.json file

```
"shellLauncher.shells.windows": [
    {
        "shell": "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\cmd.exe",
        "label": "cmd"
    },
    {
        "shell": "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
        "label": "PowerShell"
    },
    {
        "shell": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
        "label": "Git bash"
    },
    {
        "shell": "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\bash.exe",
        "label": "WSL Bash"
    }
]
```

I did confirm this will open up in the terminal window of VS Code, so it does not cause any external consoles/shells to open.

Once you have your shells configured just save the settings and then you can go to the command palette and just type "shell launch", hit enter and the choices will be displayed.
[image]

[image]

Comment: When I added the snippet provided in this answer to my `settings.json`, only Git Bash was available in the chooser. When I run with no changes to my `settings.json`, cmd, PowerShell, and Git Bash are all available. That's all I needed from the extension, so I'll just leave it, but odd behavior.

Comment: Extensions change after 2 years. I would not expect the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen a built in way to do what you want. But you can do it through tasks. Build a task that runs the command you want. Example:

tasks.json

```
{
  "taskName": "python",
  "command": "python"
},
```

Add a keybinding to run the task:

keybindings.json

```
{ "key": "ctrl+`", "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask", "args": "python" },
```

Now, whenever you press the configured keybinding, you'll get a new terminal that is running python.